# Revolution Slider clashing with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I made a website using bootstrap with Revolution Slider, i have used below jquery Files

For Bootstrap :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For Slider :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
```

My issue is that when i use Slider jquery my responsive menu slider doesn't work and vice versa..

Is there any way to solve this issue..

Thnx in advance..

Comment: have you tried to remove one of them?

Comment: yes.. no luck..

if i remove slider jquery files, then slider stops working...

Comment: have you added boostrap.js file to your site?

Comment: and I'm not sure if it's allowed to have two different versions of jquery 1.11.2/jquery.min.js and 1.7/jquery.js on one site.